# Flutter First App Exception -> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: android, flutter, connectexception

I'm trying to learn Flutter and trying to initialize first app.

I've applied all steps in Flutter getting started page but still getting exception like

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:590)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:588)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:587)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:631)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:202)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1263)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

[image: flutter doctor -v]

[image: SDK Platforms]
[image: SDK Tools]

[image: VS Code]

I've tried both standard emulator and cold boot emulator, nothing changed.
I've tried both VS Code and

```
flutter run
```

to initialize but nothing changed.
I've tried older versions of Android Studio and Pixel 6 Emulator but I got still same issue.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried both standard emulator and cold boot emulator, nothing changed.
I've tried both VS Code and flutter run to initialize but nothing changed.
I've tried older versions of Android Studio and Pixel 6 Emulators but I got still same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `android\app\build.gradle` file and try updated this

```
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android\app\build.gradle file and show the versions here:

```
println "flutter.compileSdkVersion: $flutter.compileSdkVersion"
println "android.buildToolsVersion: $android.buildToolsVersion"
println "flutter.targetSdkVersion: $flutter.targetSdkVersion"
println "flutter.minSdkVersion: $flutter.minSdkVersion"
println "flutter.ndkVersion: $flutter.ndkVersion"

android {

    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your quick response.

SDK version change is not worked, I've found the root cause that there were unnecessary proxy settings in `.gradle\gradle.properties` file. When I delete that proxy settings application is started.

Comment: You should not post an answer to add details, but you should edit your question and/or comment.